# how to distribute JS components/widgets as SAAS

Tags: javascript, web, widget, components, saas

I'm interested in creating and potentially selling javascripts that ideally can be implemented on any website, I do however have a few questions.

So far, I've have made applications in Node and Rails, where the application is just served through HTTP requests, but I don't quite understand how I can write some software, that can be injected into a site (think component/widget), while still keeping the source code hidden.

Ideally I would just give customers 1 or 2 lines of code to include in the header of their file, some credentials to authenticate against, and then have my scripts working on their site. How can this be done?

Example:
https://www.purechat.com/

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Can't be done..:) script executes in the users browser who is viewing your clients website... You can still uglify your script and serve. There are tools for that...

Comment: what can't be done? A lot of sites are doing it?

Comment: Lots of sites are magically running JavaScript in client's browser without actually sending it to client..?

Comment: No, lots of sites are distributing JS plugins/widgets as SAAS